# Displaying the contents of an NSMutableArray in a UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have this array, `NSSMutableArray *myarray`, which has five objects in it, and I am using a loop like this:

```
for( className *myObject in myarray)
{
    myTextview.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"the name is %@", myObject];
}
```

When I build and run, only the last name shows in my `UITextView *myTextview`. I logged it, and my loop is working fine -- it's showing all five objects.

The problem seems to be that each time an object is sent to the `myTextView`, the next object replaces it; is there a way I can hold all of them, so the whole array can be shown?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each time you pass the loop you are replacing `myTextview.text`. What you want is to add to the string each time. Try this:

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];
for( className *myObject in myarray) {
    [string appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"the name is %@\n", myObject]];
}
myTextview.text = string;
```

Comment: i get an error when i have NSMutbleString *string = @"";

# incompatible pointer types initializing NSMutableString with an expression of type NSString #

Comment: @Joe: Sorry about that. I was not initializing it correctly. Try it now.

Comment: @Joe: `@""` is a constant NSString. You want an NSMutableString. You'd do `string = [NSMutableString string]`.